# Disable navigation bar permanently

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm looking for a way to start Firefox (I gonna use v38+ - Windows and Linux) loading a predefined URL and with its navigation bar disabled/hidden without any option to bring navigation bar back using keyboard shortcuts or anything else besides restart it with different configuration!

Any suggestion on how doing that?

Comment: you need [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/mkiosk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need [mKiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/mkiosk/).

It is and add On  for Firefox that does exactly all that you need.

Comment: It seems to be a solution! My solution is a kind of kiosk

Comment: It seems to be a solution! My solution is a kind of kiosk as well with limited access.  Actually, the only interface users have is a keyboard. Thats why it is so importante to disable navigator bar, short cuts and anything else that could allow a user to execute/access something we don't want to. I'll take a closer look on it :) Thanks @jcbermu